# getting extra value when printing out array

Tags: c

trying to print array in ascending order but i get extra value of 123261769 may i know why?

```
int selectionSort(int num[]){
    int sml;
    sml = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (num[i] > num[j]) 
            {
                sml = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = sml;
            }
        }
    }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            printf("\n%i", num[k]);   
        }
}

int main(){
    int test[] = {5,3,2,1};
    int sortTest;
    sortTest = selectionSort(test);
    printf("%i",sortTest);
    return 0;
}
```

output

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 123261769

Comment: The array you pass in has 4 elements. You sort and print 5 accessing the array out of bounds. Normally you'd pass the size to any function that uses the array rather than assume a fixed size.

Comment: @RetiredNinja may i know how you would do "pass the size to any function that uses the array rather than assume a fixed size"?

Comment: `int selectionSort(int num[], int size) { ... }` and `sortTest = selectionSort(test, 4);`. You may also want to read [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) for a way to calculate the size as long as the array has not decayed to a pointer. You can calculate the size where it is declared but not after it has been passed to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that the array size is **4** not **5**, so instead of editing all used places for this value, you can just use macros, so type at the top :

```
#define ARR_SIZE    4
```

and at any place, there is `5` mentioned, replace it with `ARR_SIZE`.

also in the function, `selectionSort` , the return type of this function is `int` but you didn't return anything (you didn't write `return 0;` for example at the end of the function).

with that said, this is the edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARR_SIZE    4
int selectionSort(int num[]){
    int sml;
    sml = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < ARR_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (num[i] > num[j])
            {
                sml = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = sml;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < ARR_SIZE; k++)
    {
        printf("\n%i", num[k]);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int test[] = {5,3,2,1};
    int sortTest;
    sortTest = selectionSort(test);
    printf("\nreturn value from the function : %i",sortTest);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
1
2
3
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Length of the array is 4, not 5.

```
int selectionSort(int num[]){
    int sml;
    sml = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (num[i] > num[j]) 
            {
                sml = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = sml;
            }
        }
    }
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            printf("\n%i", num[k]);   
        }
}
```

If you try to access the array element out of the bound you will get undefined behaviour. You might get different results on each run. when you try to access num[5], it will increment the initial address of the array by 5 (i.e num + 5) and get whatever value is present on that memory location.